# Checkbox not getting checked via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my `.html`

```
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <div class="">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="SMSCheckbox" class="js-switch" /> SMS
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                  <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="EmailCheckBox" class="js-switch" /> Email
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
```

On my `.js`

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize() {
    console.log("loaded JS");
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "./getNotificationSettings.php",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            var bySMS = response[0].receiveSMS;
            var byEmail = response[0].receiveEmail;
            if (bySMS) {
                console.log("bySMS = true");
                $('#SMSCheckbox').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                console.log("bySMS = false");
                $('#SMSCheckbox').prop('checked', false);
            }
            if (byEmail) {
                console.log("byEmail = true");
                $('#EmailCheckBox').prop('checked', true);
            } else {
                console.log("byEmail = false");
                $('#EmailCheckBox').prop('checked', false);
            }
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    });
}
```

`bySMS = true
 byEmail = true`
I checked my console that it does go inside the if `true` branch but somehow my checkbox is not being selected. It's strange that I tested it on jsfiddle and it's working.

What could be the cause of this strange issue?

Not sure if it matters that to toggle the checkbox, I had to click on the wording. Clicking on the switch doesn't toggle it.

[image]

Comment: Upon `$(document).ready`

Comment: if that code works when you isolate it in jsFiddle then that code isn't the problem. however, you haven't set `bySMS` or `byEmail` -

Comment: MIght be a scope issue,I dont see those variables set inside the function

Comment: I am getting the values from my php file. I have tested that it does indeed run into the true branch from my console output.

Comment: Try removing  this `var response = JSON.parse(response);` line.

Comment: @Azim If I remove that the response would be `[{"receiveSMS":"1","receiveEmail":"1"}]`

Comment: Then why are you using `datatype: "json"`? @MaTaKazer

Comment: That point aside, even when I set the `if` branch to be always `true` and my `$('#SMSCheckbox').prop('checked', true);` gets executed. The checkbox is still not getting checked

Comment: see what prints for ``console.log($('#EmailCheckBox'))`` and ``console.log($('#SMSCheckbox'))``.

Comment: @YSJ It points perfectly. `outerHTML
:
"<input type="checkbox" id="EmailCheckBox" class="js-switch" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">"`

Comment: @MaTaKazer I think there are probably scripts in other section that sets the checked property back. Try put breakpoints right after property change and add watch to confirm it's changed properly.

Comment: @YSJ Hmm I checked, the checkboxes are actually checked but the image is not reflecting it. Their attribute `checked
:
true`

Comment: @MaTaKazer The code in this question apparently doesn't include anything related to image change. It's not pure css. Can't tell much from your code here. But I guess you can try add ``.change()`` like ``$('#SMSCheckbox').prop('checked', false).change();``

Comment: @YSJ. No luck. Probably take a look at the `.css`

Comment: @MaTaKazer Did you have more than one ids as id="EmailCheckBox" ?

Comment: Use **attr("checked",true)** method instead of prop.

Answer (score 0):

I always use .click() on checkboxes when changing the checked property doesn't work for some reason, not sure if this is a proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little function to handle it for you:

```
$.fn.setCheckbox = function(value) {
  var checked = $(this).attr("checked") != "undefined" &&
    ($(this).attr("checked") === "checked" ||
      $(this).attr("checked") === true);
  if (checked != value) {
    $(this).click();
  }
}
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/mdAzNsZnRdl2ifIT22e0?p=preview